# Tizen wearable web application not asking for (GPS) permissions

Tags: javascript, config, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to read my GPS data from a Samsung Gear S3, my project works when I emulate it in Tizen studio. When I run the project on a live Gear S3, it's not getting any GPS data.

I'm not getting a popup on the gear that asks me for any permissions, while I get this popup when i'm simulating the application, so I'm thinking that has something to do with the problem.

**Things I've done:**

- Gear's GPS is enabled on GPS only.
- Rebuild, clean, restarted everything, deinstalled the app every try.
- Project has a Samsung certificate
- Added a bunch of features and privileges to config.xml (see code below)

**Code**

**config.xml** *as stated above, including a bunch of, probably, unnecessary features and privileges.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/OSMLEAF" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
    <tizen:application id="5lI7dRUWxx.OSMLEAF" package="5lI7dRUWxx" required_version="2.3.1"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location.gps"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location.gps.satellite"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location.geofence"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location.batch"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>OSMLEAF</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/notification"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/setting"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/system"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/package.info"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/location"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.write"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/download"/>
    <tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
    <tizen:setting background-support="enable" encryption="disable" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

**edit: javascript from what I'm trying to do with the coords:**

```
    var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true,timeout: 0};
    function successCallback(position)
    {
        console.log("succes");

        currentGpsPosLat = position.coords.latitude;
        currentGpsPosLong = position.coords.longitude;
        marker.setLatLng([currentGpsPosLat,currentGpsPosLong]);
        console.log("going to"+ currentGpsPosLong + " -- " +currentGpsPosLat);

    }


    var marker = L.marker([0.0, 0.0],{icon:carIcon}).addTo(map);


    function errorCallback(error)
    {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error);
    }

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, options);

    window.setInterval(function(){

        marker.setLatLng([currentGpsPosLat,currentGpsPosLong]);
        map.flyTo([currentGpsPosLat,currentGpsPosLong], 17);
        }, 10000);
```

Can't find anything on the internet regarding this issue, so any help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you are trying to do ? give some example code

Comment: Hi Iqbal, I've added the javascript from what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to create an icon and constantly move the icon to the GPS position. If you need more info just let me know and thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: Is it a Tizen API ? I think this a third party api. This is not a part of Tizen may be  var marker = L.marker([0.0, 0.0],{icon:carIcon}).addTo(map);

Answer (score 0):

Didn't the Gear S3 ship with Tizen 2.3.2? This is small, but you may want to set your minimum required version from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2.

You may want to install one of the free GPS based utilities from the Samsung store just to endure that you are able to get a location fix in the environment in which you are testing. There are locations bot indoors and outside in which a good GPS fix is going to be challenging. It's worth ruling that out as a possible source of problems.

I just went back and took a look at a GPS application that I made to verify some information. I'm using the Gear S2 with cellular, which after the last firmware update behaves the same as the Gear S3 minus the MST.

You mention not getting a prompt for location permissions. The watch doesn't prompt for location permissions. The declaration for location information is necessary in the manifest (if it's not there then you won't get GPS information) and shows up as a needed permission in the app store. Once the user installs it, it just works. Note that the feature declarations don't make any functional difference in your application. Those declarations are used for the web store listing.

In the code fragment that you've shared I can't tell if currentGpsPosLat/currentGpsPosLong is in scope for the timeout function, but you shouldn't need that function since you will be setting the location when you get information back from the GPS.

In your success callback make the call to console.log *before* calling marker.setLatLng. If anything went wrong in setLatLng the function will quietly terminate and you'll have no indication of whether or not the function was even called. If you reverse the order then you'll be able to see if the function were called but failed before completion.

I only needed a couple of permissions for my application.

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/location"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
```